# Two figures side by side - positioning issue

Tags: minipage, pgf-pie

I need to put these two pie charts side by side ... to position in a CLEAN AND DECENT way while not going over page margin. It is currently okay but not really satisfying. Positioning the pie chart using `pos={-3,0}` seems not working, nor the minipage sizing.
Guide please!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{pgf-pie}   
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\pie[cloud, hide number, explode=0, text=pin, rotate=270, pos={-1,0}]  
{
94/China(94\%),
6/Other (6\%)
}  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.59\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\pie[cloud, hide number, explode=0, text=pin, rotate=90]  
{
40.8/Kazakhstan (41\%),
18.8/Pakistan (19\%),
17/Azerbaijan (17\%),
8.3/Uzbekistan (8\%),
6.4/Turkmenistan (6\%),
4.3/Mongolia (4\%),
1.8/Georgia (2\%),
1.6/Kyrgyzstan ($\sim$2\%),
1.4/Afghanistan ($\sim$1\%),
0.5/Tajikistan ($\sim$1\%)
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define radius of the biggest circle:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[cloud, hide number, explode=0, text=pin, rotate=270, 
     radius=1.5] % <---
{
94/China(\qty{94}{\%}),
6/Other (\qty{6}{\%})
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[cloud, hide number, explode=0, text=pin, rotate=90,
     radius=1.5]
{
40.8/Kazakhstan (\qty{41}{\%}),
18.8/Pakistan (\qty{19}{\%}),
17/Azerbaijan (\qty{17}{\%}),
8.3/Uzbekistan (\qty{8}{\%}),
6.4/Turkmenistan (\qty{6}{\%}),
4.3/Mongolia (\qty{4}{\%}),
1.8/Georgia (\qty{2}{\%}),
1.6/Kyrgyzstan (\qty{\sim2}{\%}),
1.4/Afghanistan (\qty{\sim1}{\%}),
0.5/Tajikistan (\qty{\sim1}{\%})
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Zarko, thnaks. Your diagram looks good in terms of position and size. However, the code doesn't run apparently due to the `(\qty{94}{\%})` arrangement. Second, the last country dropped perhaps while it was there in the original diagram!

Comment: @AmosMachado, you should have installed recent version of `siunitx` package. If you still stick with older, version 2 package, than replace `\qty` with  `\SI`. The second problem is not addressed in your question, however `pin` position is hardwire in the code, so there is no (simple) way to directed it to other direction.

Comment: The `siunitx`  issue is fixed, thanks. Related to the second issue, we have ten countries in the second part but it shows only nine.

Comment: @AmosMachado, ups, I had spurious `%` in code. Now are removed, however, the result does not look nice. To my opinion, you should use some other graphic presentation or draw your image directly in `tikz` (or rewrite `pgf-pie` style)

Comment: The option explode works for that. Taking explode value equal to something like 0.3 widens up the circle, hence enhancing clarity of labels. It looks now reasonably good. Thanks for your help :)